# How to concat string in Ionic 4 with the template?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to contact the name and surname in my Ionic 4 Full Starter kit template:

```
 <app-text-shell [data]="customer?.surname + customer?.name"></app-text-shell>
```

Unfortunately there is not the space between them; how Can I do? If I create a function in customer link getNameAndSurname() there is a message error.

Comment: Can you provide us the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Pass this way

```
<app-text-shell [data]="customer?.surname +" "+ customer?.name"></app-text-shell>
```

add space

```
+" "+
```

or

```
customer = { surname: "weerasinghe", name: "chanaka" };
```

.html

```
<app-text-shell [data]="customer"></app-text-shell>
```

Access data

```
 this.data.surname
```

Comment: And with the function customer.getNameAndSurname()?

Comment: Updated check it

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my idea is to create a function in the customer.ts to call it in the html file, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The above answer did work for me in Ionic 4 with little enhancement. Replacing "" with '' inside the data property.

```
<app-text-shell [data]="details?.min_salary+' '+details?.min_salary"></app-text-shell>
```

Answer (score 0):

When 'customer' is defined but contains only empty properties, then this will end up showing 'undefined undefined', instead of the app shell (at least for me), because that added space does make it non-empty.
So my solution is instead of this:

```
<app-text-shell [data]="details?.min_salary+' '+details?.min_salary"></app-text-shell>
```

Use this:

```
<app-text-shell [data]="details.min_salary? details.min_salary+' '+details.min_salary : ''"></app-text-shell>
```